# Strcpy segfaults after Malloc

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc, strcpy

So, i was writing a a simple slice function in C, which takes an array of strings, the string that marks the beginning of the slice, and the size of the slice. in the function i malloc a new array, and then proceed to copy over each string in the slice to the new array. however, i get a segfault on the very first strcpy, even though i've already malloced space for the result array.

the code looks like this:

```
char** slice(char** args, char* start, int size){
  int i = 0;
  // need to find start first
  char* cursor = args[0];
  int j = 0;
  while(cursor != NULL){
    if(strcmp(cursor, start) == 0){
      break;
    }
    j++;
    cursor = args[j];
  }
  char** result = malloc(MAX_INPUT * size);
  while(i < size){
    strcpy(result[i], args[j+i]);
    i++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

the line which casues the segfault is --

```
strcpy(result[i], args[j+i]);
```

i've used gdb to peek into the values of whats in result and args,
result[i] is 0x0, which is NULL, but result itself is an address but i'm not sure why malloc isn't working. have i run out of stack space? does this mean i'm screwed?

Comment: this is a question about a run time problem, so the posted code must cleanly compile, and when run display the problem.  The posted code is missing the #include header file statements and there is no driver for the function I.E. no main() function and no description of the 'args[]' parameter contents and no example input.  Since the problem seems to be with the 'argss[]' parameter the code that sets that parameter needs to be posted

Comment: the posted code fails to check (!=NULL) the returned value so how do you know the malloc() failed?

Comment: What is the #define for MAX_INPUT?  How does 'size' relate to the 'args[]' parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result[i]` is an uninitialized pointer. You have made the same error as in:

```
char *ptr;
strcpy(ptr, args[j+i]);
```

You must make `result[i]` point to some allocated space before you can copy characters into it. Also, `MAX_INPUT * size` is the wrong amount of space to allocate for an array of pointers.

Another problem is that if `size` is bigger than the number of strings remaining in the array after `start` then you read off the end of the array.

Then your function never placs a `NULL` at the end of the new array, so the caller has no way of knowing how big the slice is that you have returned.

Also `cursor` is redundant, you could have just written `args[j]`. Basically the function is a complete mess.

The code could be (warning: untested):

```
char** slice(char** args, char const *start, int slice_size)
{
// Find index of "start"
    int start_index;

    for (start_index = 0; args[start_index]; ++start_index)
         if ( !strcmp(args[start_index], start) )
              break;

// Abort if "start" was not present (remove this line if you want to
// instead return an empty terminated list)
    if ( !args[start_index] )
         return NULL;

// Allocate array of pointers to new strings, allowing space for terminator
    char **result = malloc((slice_size + 1) * sizeof *result);
    if ( !result )
        return NULL;

// Copy strings in, allocating space for each string, stopping if no more args
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < slice_size && args[start_index + i]; ++i)
         result[i] = strdup(args[start_index + i]);

// Terminate the list
    result[i] = NULL;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked. yeah, i suppose cursor was unnecessessary,.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
char** result = malloc(MAX_INPUT * size);
```

mallocs MAX_INPUT characters times size.  What is the meaning of the contents of 'size'.

Overall, what is needed is a malloc for a number of `char *` which I do not see in the code.

Then, after getting that malloc parameter correct,

The code needs to use `strdup()` rather than `strcpy()` -or- malloc room for each string and then use `strcpy()`, probably in a loop containing both function calls